how can i fix the error code that i keep on receiving?
hi I'm trying to put a reset button on my google spreadsheet, but every time i try to run the script i keep on getting this error code

Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
ClearCells    @ Code.gs:3**

the code I've put in is as follows (keep in mind I'm new at this and i copied a script that i found online)
function ClearCells() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('xxxxxxxxxx');
 sheet
.getRange('B14:15,B20:B27,C7:C11,C13:C14,C20:C27,D7:D14,E13:E14,F7:F14,G7:G27,H7:H27,I7:I16,J7:J16,K7:K27,L7:L27,M7:M63,N7:N63,O7:O63,P7:P63,Q7:Q63,R7:R63,S7:S63,T7:T63,U7:U63,V7:V63,W7:W63,X7:X63,Y7:Y63,Z7:Z63,AB7:AB63')
.clearContent();
}

I've tried tweaking it but nothing seems to change


var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('xxxxxxxxxx');
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange') ClearCells @ Code.gs:3

The error indicates that there is no tab named xxxxxxxxxx in the spreadsheet. Check the tab name for things like leading or trailing spaces.

sheet.getRange('B14:15,B20:B27,C7:C11,...

That syntax does not work with the Sheet.getRange() method. Use Sheet.getRangeList() instead.

thanks for the response, i changes the sheet name as well as the formula to 'Sheet.getRangeList(). but nothing has changed

Sheet.getRangeList() expects an array of A1 type range references.
